# Is it possible to get a proxy onto a bytearray?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to allocate a large bytearray, but also divide it up into a number of smaller bytearray-like objects. When the smaller objects are modified, they should modify the underlying bytearray.

I've tried both of the following strategies.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
b = bytearray(10)
c = b[5:]
c = bytearray(1 for d in c)
pp(c)
pp(b)
```

and

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
b = bytearray(10)
c = b[5:]
for i in range(len(c)):
  c[i] = 1
pp(c)
pp(b)
```

They both output

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01')
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

My aim would be to have a similar piece of code, which outputs

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01')
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01')
```

That is, when `c` is updated, `b` is also updated in the appropriate position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[memoryview](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) is close to what you want

```
>>> b = bytearray(10)
>>> c = memoryview(b)[5:]
>>> c[:] = bytearray(1 for d in c)
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01')
```

you have to use `c.tobytes()` or pass `c` to bytearray to see it's contents

```
>>> c.tobytes()
'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01'
>>> bytearray(c)
bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01')
```

Comment: Why hello @gnibbler. Fancy seeing you here.